# How do I make a loop for this specific code

Tags: javascript, loops

I know the code I'm making is really simple but I have tried to watch so many tutorials and make those code work in my JavaScript code but I just can't seem to understand. Some help as soon as possible would be useful. I'm trying to simplify this code into a loop and it's suppose to ask the user how many is coming to the party and than asking a follow-up question of the names of the guests depending on how many is coming.
gjester=guests

```
var gjester = prompt("How many is coming to your party?");
if (gjester == 1){
    var name1 = prompt("What is the name of guest 1?"); 
    console.log("Yey " + name1 + " is coming to your party")
}
if (gjester == 2){
    var name1 = prompt("What is the name of guest 1?");
    var name2 = prompt("What is the name of guest 2?");
    console.log("Yey " + name1 + " is coming to your party");
    console.log("Yey " + name2 + " is coming to your party")
}

//and so on//
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved using a simple for loop

```js
let gjester = prompt("How many is coming to your party?");

let names = []
for(let i = 0; i<gjester ; i++) {
   names.push(prompt(`What is the name of guest ${i+1}?`))
     console.log("Yey " + names[i] + " is coming to your party");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a do/while loop like so:

```
var count = prompt("How many is coming to your party?");
var names = []
do {
    let name = prompt("What is the name of guest "  + count + "?");
    names.push(name);
    count--
} while (count > 0)
```

Comment: Infinite loop !. you forgot to decrement count value.

Comment: oops, probably broke OPs computer